# Symfony2 - how can I transfer service into another service in array

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, dependency-injection

I cannot transfer service into another service in array.

For example this is my `config.yml`:

```yaml
services:
    car.price.calculator:
        class:        My\SuperBundle\CarCalculator
        arguments:    "something"

product_viewer:
    car:
        rest_client: "@car.price.calculator"  # <- this is the service I cannot transfer
        rest_url: http://example.com
```

and `service.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <service id="product.browser" class="Mrok\ShopBundle\Price\Calculator">
            <argument key="car" type="collection">
                <argument key="rest_client">%product.browser.rest_client%</argument>
                <argument key="rest_url">%product.browser.rest_url%</argument>
            </argument>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

my MrokShopExtension rewrites data from configuration into container parameters, ex

```php
 $container->setParameter('product.browser.rest_client', $config[0]['car']['rest_client']);
```

`Calculator` class:

```
class Calculator {

private $set;

public function __contruct(array $set) {
    $this->set = $set;
    var_dump($set);
}
```

and as a result I got (`var_dump` from code):

```
   array (size=2)
     'rest_client' => string '@car.price.calculator' <- and here is a problem, it is a string, should be object
```

How instead of getting the string as `rest_client` get class instance (service).
I cannot change argument into:

```xml
<argument type="service" id="car.price.calculator" />
```

because I do not know what kind of service will end user inject.

I know I can pass whole container and service id as parameter - but I would like to avoid injecting container.

Comment: pass to your service (a)service.container and get another service with container or maybe need no '(a)car.price.calculator', but '%car.price.calculator%'

Comment: xcompl - I do not want to pass whole container, I would like to inject only services which I need

Comment: Basically you can use compiler pass. (See http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html) You can use then addArgument... something like that `$definition->addArgument(new Reference($container->getParameter('product.browser.rest_client')));` Please see http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/components/dependency_injection/definitions.html as well.

Comment: I think for renaming a service you should use `setAlias` rather than `setParameter` and then just use `car.price.calculator` without the `@`.